# Angular: nested router-outlet is always ignored

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Do you have any idea what might be wrong with my configuratoin if my second router-outlet is always ignored? This here is my app.module routing (app.component has one router-outlet):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule',
    canLoad: [AuthorizationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'please-login',
    component: PleaseLoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'please-login'
  }
];
```

And here is my home.module-routing (HomeComponent has another router-outlet):

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'welcome',
        component: WelcomeComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'welcome'
  },
  {
    path: 'Data',
    loadChildren: '@libs/data#DataModule'
  }
]),
```

I can load DataModule with no problems; it directs me to /home/data/blabla. But (!) it inserts DataComponent into the first router-outlet. The second one (and thus the whole HomeComponent which is supposed to surround DataComponent) is ignored. That is, unless I navigate to /home, then it is displayed, but as expected, with no DataComponent inside. Meaning I can use both components only exclusively and not nested.

I tried using named outlets, but to no success. When I trace-log the router-state, the resolves seem to be ok, so I am a bit lost here

Comment: The router-outlet in the home component is where the component of the matched child route will be inserted. Your home route has a single child route 'welcome'. So if you go to /home/welcome, the WelcomeComponent will be inserted there. For any other route, you won't be in a child route of the default home route, so nothing will be inserted.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, I have adjusted my code accordingly (I think you and SiddAjmera had the same idea). But I still get an error  (see my comment to the answer) with this configuration. Do you know why?

Comment: @Phil, with a great catch from JBNizet, I've updated my answer. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `DataComponent` load in the `router-outlet` of the HomeComponent(which means you'll have to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your `HomeComponent` template as well), you will have to make `data` as a child of the `''` path.

Another thing that you'll have to do is remove `pathMatch: 'full'` from your `''` route. What it would do is, try to match the path in chunks, i.e. if `''` is matched, it will try to check for any matching child routes.

Finally, I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but the path should be `data` and NOT `Data`.

All this would translate to code something like this:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'data',
        loadChildren: '@libs/data#DataModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'welcome',
        component: WelcomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/welcome',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]),
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But unfortunately, I get `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/welcome'` after the redirect from the login (/login) with this configuration. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Remove the pathMatch: 'full' of your base route.

Comment: @JBNizet, aahhh. Good catch. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! It works without the patchMatch: 'full' !